# transfer a zip file from one windows machine to another

Tags: batch-file

How can we transfer a zip file from one windows machine to another using windows batch script?

I tried using copy command, but it says can't identify the destination URL.

Answer (score 0):

User Robocopy.exe.

Using powershell you can use copy-item together with -ToSession

```
help new-pssession
$x = get-pssession
copy-item -source file -destination file -ToSession $x
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Can you help one more step. how to iput credentials while creating session?